# Twitter Bootstrap error when running 'bootstrap:themed', with Mongo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-rails

This occurs when I try to run `rails g bootstrap:themed Associations` in my terminal:

```
C:/Users/ruby/.pik/rubies/Ruby-193-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-2.1.9/lib/generators/bootstrap/themed/themed_generator.rb:87:in `block in retrieve_columns': undefined method `columns' for Association:Class (NoMethodError)
```

It just can't seem to work, I've tried many ways, searched everywhere, never succesful. I'm using Mongo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just got exact same error. I created two identical project - one with mongoid and one without. I only get the error on the mongoid project.

Found this workaround that seems to solve the problem:

Remove references to ActiveRecord (around line 87) in the file:

```
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bundler/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-b8b7eb22614a/lib/generators/bootstrap/themed/themed_generator.rb
```

I changed ...

```
  def retrieve_columns
    if defined?(ActiveRecord)
      rescue_block ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid do
        @model_name.constantize.columns
      end
    else
      rescue_block do
        @model_name.constantize.fields.map {|c| c[1] }
      end
    end
  end
```

to this ...

```
  def retrieve_columns
      rescue_block do
        @model_name.constantize.fields.map {|c| c[1] }
      end
  end
```

To get the views working I needed to make sure that my model class had a created_at field that wasn't nil (alternatively edit the generated views).

Hope this helps.

PS: Wow  ... it seems you've got twitter-bootstrap-rails working on windows - I didn't know that was possible!

Comment: Yeah heheh now I'm using Ubuntu too... I actually got it to work by downgrading twitter-bootstrap-rails to '2.0.2', but maybe it isn't a permanent fix so I'll try your fix! Thank you very much!

Comment: Cool - good to hear. I'll send the link to twitter-boostrap-rails maintainers so they can find a permanent solution independent of ActiveRecord.